# how to show data in gridview based on the selection on dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, datatable

I have a dropdown list like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPortal2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>TRAVELONG</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ONETRAVEL</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and a grid view with sqlconnection:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns> 
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Portal" HeaderText="Portal" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TID" HeaderText="TID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PNR" HeaderText="PNR" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNumber" HeaderText="Ticket Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ESACCode" HeaderText="ESACCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WaiverCode" HeaderText="WaiverCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnusedTicketAmount" HeaderText="UnusedTicketAmount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlUnusedAmount" HeaderText="ddlUnusedAmount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AirlinePenality" HeaderText="AirlinePenality" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlAirlinePenality" HeaderText="ddlAirlinePenality" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NetRefundProcess" HeaderText="NetRefundProcess" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlNetRefundProcess" HeaderText="ddlNetRefundProcess" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundableCommission" HeaderText="RefundableCommission" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlRefundableCommission" HeaderText="ddlRefundableCommission" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CouponRefunded" HeaderText="CouponRefunded" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundType" HeaderText="RefundType" /> 
    </Columns>       
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BartConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT select * [Test]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now when i select Travelong from my dropdown list and press search button all the data show in the gridview can any one tell me how to do that.
how can i do that 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SqlDataSource.FilterExpression Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression.aspx)

Comment: can you explain through code what query i have to fire on my search button so that datatable is filled and i can bind that datatable with my gridview

Answer (score 1):

Use [SelectParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx) property of SqlDataSource

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPortal2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>TRAVELONG</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ONETRAVEL</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BartConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT select * [Test] WHERE Portal = @Portal"">
      <selectparameters>
          <asp:controlparameter name="Portal" controlid="ddlPortal2" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
      </selectparameters>
  </asp:sqldatasource>
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx)

Comment: "Select select ?? what's that

Comment: please go through the provided link, there is sample which will be helpful.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx

Comment: i guess no one has solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlConnection con;
    if (ddlPortal2.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bart;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Test where Portal='"+ddlPortal2.SelectedValue+"' and CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), [DateTime], 101) between '" + tbFrom.Text + "' and '" + tbTo.Text + "'", con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
    else if (ddlPortal2.SelectedValue == "All")
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bart;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Test where Portal=Portal", conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Use select parameters for your SQL datasource. You don't have to write all this plumbing code.